# Using C++ standard libraries with the Windows Desktop Wizard in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, desktop-application

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-160).

Here's the code I'm using, copied from that site:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Global variables

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour Application");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(
   _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
   _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
   _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
   WNDCLASSEX wcex;

   wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
   wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
   wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
   wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
   wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
   wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
   wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
   wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
   wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
   wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
   wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
   wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

   if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
   {
      MessageBox(NULL,
         _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
         _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
         NULL);

      return 1;
   }

   // Store instance handle in our global variable
   hInst = hInstance;

   // The parameters to CreateWindowEx explained:
   // WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW : An optional extended window style.
   // szWindowClass: the name of the application
   // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
   // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
   // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
   // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
   // NULL: the parent of this window
   // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
   // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
   // NULL: not used in this application
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
      WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      szWindowClass,
      szTitle,
      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
      500, 100,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      hInstance,
      NULL
   );

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      MessageBox(NULL,
         _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
         _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
         NULL);

      return 1;
   }

   // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
   // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
   // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
   ShowWindow(hWnd,
      nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   // Main message loop:
   MSG msg;
   while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
   {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }

   return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   PAINTSTRUCT ps;
   HDC hdc;
   TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, Windows desktop!");

   switch (message)
   {
   case WM_PAINT:
      hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

      // Here your application is laid out.
      // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows desktop!"
      // in the top left corner.
      TextOut(hdc,
         5, 5,
         greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
      // End application-specific layout section.

      EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
      break;
   case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
   default:
      return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
      break;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I'd like to now modify the program for my own needs, including for example the use of `<vector>` and `<fstream>`.

However when I include fstream and try to declare an fstream object either as a global variable or within the `winMain` function, I get the following error: `identifier fstream is undefined`. Similarly for `<vector>`. Including `cmath` and then using the `cos` function, however, causes no problems.

Comment: Your current code does not seem to include or use fstream.

Comment: You did `#include <fstream>` and `#include<vector>` at the top of your program, right?

Comment: try putting `std::` before `fstream`

Comment: I just copy/pasted the code from that site. In my modified code, I put `#include <fstream>` at the top and then for example declare an fstream object - `fstream anFstream` - where it says "global variables".

Comment: @Jeffrey yes this seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include a directive for `using namespace std;`. This way `fstream` will be recognized by the compiler, since it belongs within the `std` namespace. Otherwise, you must write `std::fstream` in order to access this class.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)